# Is there a way to start a new thread from dialog and use it in mainwindow in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function that downloads a torrent file. I need to download the torrent in a separate thread from the GUI thread, so I used QtConcurrent::run to start the download in another thread, but I started the download in a dialog and the dialog closes immediatly after the download has started, and (I'm new to qt, so I think) closing the dialog, the dialog object gets deleted and with the dialog QFuture and QFutureWatcher are also deleted and, since QFutureWatcher doesn't exists anymore, it doesn't emit the finished signal. Can someone tell me how to fix this and if what I wrote above is true?

Here is the code i use to start the download:

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_downloadButton_clicked {
  DownloadDialog ddl_dial;
  ddl_dial.exec();
}
```

downloaddiaolg.cpp

```
on_finishButton_clicked() {
  TorrentDDL tddl;
  QFutureWatcher<void> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>;
  QFuture<void> tddl_thread = QtConcurrent::run(&TorrentDDL::download, 
  &tddl, magnet_str_url, file_path);
  watcher->setFuture(tddl_thread);
  close();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: Use signals and slots from the thread to notifty the GUI that the operation is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog gets deleted because it goes out of scope because it's instantiated on stack. Use heap.

```
DownloadDialog* ddl_dial = new DownloadDialog(this);
ddl_dial->exec();
```

Don't forget to delete it at some point to avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

GUI has one thread in QT. please see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread)

> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
> thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
> Qt applications). **The Qt GUI must run in this thread.** All **widgets** and
> **several related classes**, for example, QPixmap, don't work in secondary
> threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker
> thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main
> thread.

But you can have a separate class for downloading and then inherit it from [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html).

You can use worker objects by moving them to the thread using `QObject::moveToThread()`.

Comment: I've edited my question hoping it will now be clearer, but the problem is that since the QFutureWatcher object gest deleted, I can't communicate anymore with my downloader in the worker thread. (Yes, sorry, I wasn't very clear, I apologize)